# Design business card App

Tags: web-apps, business-card

Do you know an App to do this?

I read Microsoft Publisher software is not available for Mac. This program has nice templates, just what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you need an app? There are many web sites which will let you design business cards online (if you print your cards through the company).  Or you could use Google Docs, or any of the other online Office suites, too.

Comment: I believe there are also templates for Microsoft Word or any other (more or less) popular text editor. I remember using Word to print folder labels. Just if you want to print on both sides of the business card you can run into some problems.